# How to use use enum Name inside of toList foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

Currently I am showing enum name value in view like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DrawDatesList)
{
    <tr id="tableHeadRows">
        <td class="tableHeadRowsInside">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LotteryId)
        </td>
        <td class="tableHeadRowsInside">
            @Enum.GetName(typeof(MediaBug.Shared.Enumerators.Days), item.DayId)
        </td>
```

...

It works ok.

But this is used in foreach pagedList.
I retreive it in my action like this:

```
    var results = ClientRepositoryBuilder
                    .Instance
                    .LotteryClientRepository
                    .GetAllDrawDates()
                    .ToPagedList(page, this.pageSize);
    var model = new LotteryIndexViewModel();
    model.DrawDatesList = results;

    return this.PartialView(model);
```

Is there any option that I do not use @Enum.GetName(typeof(MediaBug.Shared.Enumerators.Days), item.DayId) in View and somehow assign it in action in Model? But I don't know how to, because you have to use it in foreach and you can't "insert" it into ToList.

Comment: What is `item.DayId`?

Answer (score 0):

What type of object is DrawDatesList? Let's say it's IEnumerable. Then DrawDate could look like this:

```
public class DrawDate {
    public int DayId { get; set; }
    public int LotteryId { get; set; }
    public string DayName { get { return Enum.GetName(typeof(MediaBug.Shared.Enumerators.Days), DayId); } }
    // other properties here if applicable
}
```

Alternatively, you could replace DayName above with this:

```
    public string DayName { get { return ((MediaBug.Shared.Enumerators.Days) DayId).ToString(); } }
```

(Just a matter of semantics.)

And in your view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DrawDatesList)
{
    <tr id="tableHeadRows">
        <td class="tableHeadRowsInside">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LotteryId)
        </td>
        <td class="tableHeadRowsInside">
            item.DayName
        </td>
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do you actually use DayId from ToList, to get proper DayIds, where to assign the value through ToList?